# android filedialog then upload to server

Tags: android, filedialog

For my Activity i have two buttons, one is to pick a file using FileDialog, and then the other one is to upload it. My problem here is getting the value of the file from the FileDialog. I'm just using toast in my FileDialog method so that i can see the file name being selected. I'm using this one as a reference [click here.](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)  How can i get the filename and the path of the file and then place it in a string variable. Can you help me with these? Sorry I'm a novice.

FileDialog method

```
public static void openDialogToUploadFile(final Activity activity,final Context context) {

    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//DIR//");

    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(activity, mPath);
    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(".txt");

    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "File: "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    fileDialog.showDialog();
}
```

In here i want the value of the uploadFileName and uploadFilePath will be coming from the FileDialog method. How can i achieve this?

Reference Class:

UploadToServer.java

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                    }
                                });                      

                             uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                        }
                      }).start();        
                }
            });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
          File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

          if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

               dialog.dismiss(); 

               Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                                   +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                       messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                   }
               }); 

               return 0;

          }
          else
          {
               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""
                                             + fileName + """ + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 

           } // End else block 
         } 
}
```

Comment: Simple just use **SharedPreference** and save the file path or file name whatever you want. And get it in your **UploadtoServer** Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give up the thinking of **save** the name and path, and grab it later. Simply work on it directly, like below, pass in extra arguments if you need to.

```
public static void openDialogToUploadFile(final Activity activity,final Context context) {

    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//DIR//");

    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(activity, mPath);
    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(".txt");

    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "File: "+file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            doSomething(file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath())
        }
    });
    fileDialog.showDialog();
}

public static void doSomething(String name, String path) {
     //work with what you want here
}
```